# Codeigniter mod_rewrite gives server 500 error

Tags: php, codeigniter

I get an server 500 error with this htaccesss file in my xampp enviorment.

My `$config['index_page']` variable is set to `''`

`C:/xampp/htdocs/codeigniter_test/.htaccess`

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /codeigniter_test/

#Removes access to the system folder by users.
#Additionally this will allow you to create a System.php controller,
#previously this would not have been possible.
#'system' can be replaced if you have renamed your system folder.
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^system.*
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]

#When your application folder isn't in the system folder
#This snippet prevents user access to the application folder
#Submitted by: Fabdrol
#Rename 'application' to your applications folder name.
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^application.*
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]

#Checks to see if the user is attempting to access a valid file,
#such as an image or css document, if this isn't true it sends the
#request to index.php
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
<IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>
# If we don't have mod_rewrite installed, all 404's
# can be sent to index.php, and everything works as normal.
# Submitted by: ElliotHaughin

    ErrorDocument 404 /index.php
</IfModule>
```

So if I go to `localhost/codeigniter_test/site/home` now I get this server 500 error.

`site = controller` and `home = function in the site controller which loads up the home view`

Also `localhost/codeigniter_test/site/about` is not working for me.
I don't get any 404 page so this means my `mod_rewrite` module is enabled.
I also checked this in my `httpd.conf` file.

Apache logs says:

> [core:alert] [pid 1484:tid 512] [client 127.0.0.1:3870] C:/xampp/htdocs/codeigniter_test/.htaccess:

Edit: So I just removed the entire IF part.
Now localhost/codeigniter_test/  works.
But if I go to localhost/codeigniter_test/site/home it doesnt work and I get an 404 page.

Edit2: I change AllowOverride None to AllowOverride All in my httpd conf file.
Now I get a 403 error when I go to:  localhost/codeigniter_test/site/home/

"The requested URL /codeigniter_test/site/home was not found on this server."

Answer (score 0):

I got similar issue, basically, it's a permission issue:

try granting 755 permission on the folders and subfolders

```
chmod 755 *
chmod 755 */*
chmod 755 */*/*
chmod 755 */*/*/*
chmod 755 */*/*/*/*
```

I only have this in my .htaccess file

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule .* index.php/$0 [PT,L]
```

Hope that helps

Comment: These folders doesnt exists just FYI. So if I set 755 on the whole CI folder structure, people can check out the entire view folder for instance. Not something you would like.